# Transparent bounding box of an ellipse

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, gdi

I'm writing some C++ code to draw ellipses. Sometimes these ellipses could be stacked on top of each other in a grouping. When they are stacked on each other, I'd like to have the bounding box of the ellipse be transparent so that I don't see the white corners of the bounding box. See picture below.

[image]

Including the `SetBkMode` or not doesn't seem to make a difference. If I don't do the `FillRect`, I get a black background on the bounding box.

```
HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
CDC *pDC = CDC::FromHandle(pSprite->hDCMem);
pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
pDC->FillRect(m_SpriteRect, CBrush::FromHandle(brush));
pDC->SelectObject(m_BackBrush);
pDC->Ellipse(m_SpriteRect);
pDC->SetBkMode(OPAQUE);

DeleteObject(brush);
```

Is there a way to set a transparent background?

Comment: Just remove `FillRect`. It looks like you are drawing on memory dc, so that may cause a different problem depending on what you are doing. It will be a bit more complicated if you are making a sprite...

Comment: @Barmak If I don't use FillRect, the bounding box background is black. At least white background looks better.

Comment: Show the rest of your code where you paint the memory dc on final dc. Try `TransparentBlt` with the same color.

Comment: @Barmak - TransparentBlt was the answer. If you want to post it as an answer to my question, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If drawing on memory dc, fill the background with a transparent color, then use `TransparentBlt` to blit the memory dc on to final `HDC`. Example:

```
CDC *pDC = CDC::FromHandle(hDCMem);

//fill the background with transparent color
COLORREF clr_transparent = RGB(255, 255, 255); //<- randomly selected color
CBrush brush(clr_transparent);
pDC->FillRect(m_SpriteRect, &brush);

//any drawing
auto oldbrush = pDC->SelectObject(m_BackBrush);
pDC->Ellipse(m_SpriteRect);
pDC->SelectObject(oldbrush);

//transparent blit
TransparentBlt(final_hdc, x_dest, y_dest, width, height, 
    hDCMem, 0, 0, m_SpriteRect.right, m_SpriteRect.bottom, clr_transparent);
```

Comment: Or blit from the background to the memory DC first.